# check if text content numbers separated by anything

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to check if text contains at least six numbers. We can use:

```
/([0-9]{6,})/
```

but when the text is like this "0-1-2-4-4-6" or "0a1r2a4a4a6", etc. What's the right regex to detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
(.*\d.*){6,}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(?>\d\D*){6}
```